# Additional (2nd) battery is detected but not charged

Tags: 20.04, power-management, hardware, battery, fujitsu-siemens

I have Ubuntu 20.04 running on a Fujitsu Lifebook s761 with two batteries. Both batteries are detected but only the main one is charged. Previously, Windows was running on the laptop and the second battery worked as intended and was charged.

Does anyone have an idea why the battery is not charging and a suggestion on how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance, toni

See below the issue of upower:

```
upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_CMB1
native-path: CMB1
vendor: Fujitsu
model: CP483691-01
serial: 02A-Z110717001000Z
power supply: yes
updated: Di 21 Sep 2021 09:10:49 CEST (87 seconds ago)
has history: yes
has statistics: yes
battery
present: yes
rechargeable: yes
state: fully-charged
warning-level: none
energy: 66,96 Wh
energy-empty: 0 Wh
energy-full: 66,96 Wh
energy-full-design: 66,96 Wh
energy-rate: 0 W
voltage: 12,318 V
percentage: 100%
capacity: 100%
technology: lithium-ion
icon-name: 'battery-full-charged-symbolic'

upower -i /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_CMB2
native-path: CMB2
vendor: Fujitsu
model: CP384580-01
serial: 03A-T110328000054T
power supply: yes
updated: Di 21 Sep 2021 09:00:57 CEST (53 seconds ago)
has history: yes
has statistics: yes
battery
present: yes
rechargeable: yes
state: charging
warning-level: none
energy: 0 Wh
energy-empty: 0 Wh
energy-full: 27 Wh
energy-full-design: 27 Wh
energy-rate: 0 W
percentage: 0%
capacity: 100%
technology: lithium-ion
icon-name: 'battery-caution-charging-symbolic'
History (charge):
1632207657 0,000 unknown
History (rate):
1632207657 0,000 unknown
```

Comment: Ubuntu does not charge any batteries. That is done by the hardware. Maybe trying re wording your question so it does apply to the OS.

Comment: That is correct. I updated the description of the problem. Thanks.